# Javascript class not being loaded on feature tests with Capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, sprockets

I have a `coffee` class which is called in the `create.js.coffee` file. **It works fine on development**.
However when running feature tests (with `Capybara` and `web-kit`), it seems that this class isn't getting loaded properly.

These are the files:

*assets/javascript/app_init.js.coffee*

```
window.MyApp = { }
```

*assets/javascript/modules/product_module.js.coffee*

```
window.MyApp.ProductModule = class ProductModule
  @show: ->
    # Do stuff
```

*assets/javascript/application.js*

```
//= require app_init
//= require_tree .
```

And the *create.js.coffee*

```
console.log window.MyApp => Returns [Object Object]
console.log window.MyApp.ProductModule => Returns undefined
```

These returns are what I get when running the specs and debugging. Any ideas?

I am using **Rails 5** if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I run `rails assets:precompile` and it fixed the tests. I am not sure why I needed to precompile assets to run the test. I might have something wrong at the configuration. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `test.rb` file configuration, doesn't include the assets compile anymore. The solution to this is to add this to `test.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = true
```